# foreach not working in Drupal 7

Tags: for-loop, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to execute following code to trace array value in drupal module. But it's not working. In PHP my code works fine but shows notice in Drupal. How to write `foreach` in Drupal module?

```
foreach($submission as $s) {
  foreach ($s as $a) {
    echo $sid = $a[1]->sid; 
  }
}
```

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in webform_submission_publish() (line 149
>   of

Comment: Why you thinking that foreach loop not working? $a[1] is undefined and it is all.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an undefined offset, the code will break.

You can prevent this kind of mistake by checking if the array is set.

```
foreach ($submission as $s) {
  foreach ($s as $a) {
    if (isset($a[1])) {
      echo $sid = $a[1]->sid;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you can check for the index 1 before using it, but it's a bit odd to access the value indexed by 1, which is likely to be the second element in the array. You can get the first element using the [PHP reset() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php). So, the echo line would read

```
echo $sid = reset($a)->sid;
```